# Is there any other way to convert RGB to HSI?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb

I'm trying to convert RGB message into HSI in python and here is my code:

```
#pre_proc
rows, cols = pixels.shape[0], pixels.shape[1]
# transpose to 3 * pixels_number
# utilized for extract R/G/B cols
t_p = pixels.swapaxes(0, 2).swapaxes(1, 2)
R, G, B = t_p[0], t_p[1], t_p[2]
dRG, dRB, dGB = R - G, R - B, G - B # all belongs to [0,255]
dRG[dRG == 0.0] = 0.5
dRB[dRB == 0.0] = 0.5 
dGB[dGB == 0.0] = 0.5 # just ignore my divide_zero exception handler
# H part
cos = (dRG+dRB)/(2*numpy.sqrt(dRG**2+dRB*dGB))
H = numpy.arccos(cos)
H[numpy.isnan(H)] = 0.0 # if cos is too big, arccos returns nan
# I part
I = pixels.mean(axis = 2)
# prepare for Saturation calc
Imin = pixels.min(axis = 2)
I[I == 0.0] = 1
# S part
S = 1 - Imin / I
```

My question is, this procedure costs almost 0.24s @ 1000*1000 pixels image which is unbearable in that my application has to be able to deal with images in ms-level, 0.02s is acceptable.
For you convenience, I used time.clock() to measure pre_proc, H, S and I part respectively and I found that pre_proc cost 0.041s, H cost 0.088s, I cost 0.075s and S cost 0.013s.
Is there any library that could do this faster? Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you'll use the OpenCV library. It has fast implementations for a wide range of image processing and computer vision operations, including color conversions. It has a Python API.

See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html) for documentation on the cvtColor method, which is the OpenCV method for color space transformations. The transformation from RGB to HSI is called CV_RGB2HLS in OpenCV.

Comment: Are you sure about the existence of hsi converter in OpenCV as this is costly for I only need to use the HSI<->RGB convertion?

Comment: In OpenCV, you can use the cvtColor function with the CV_RGB2HLS flag to do an RGB->HSI conversion.

Comment: Oh, I found that colorsys contains the rgb_to_hls function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442285/converting-rgb-to-hls-and-back

Comment: Isn't HLS same as HSL Model, in HSI Model, the intensity plane is an average of R, G and B planes.

Comment: HSI is not the same as HLS/HSL. Both Saturation and Intensity of HSI are different than Saturation and Value of HSV. See [Lightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness) and [Saturation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Saturation) on Wikipedia.